# Getting error while reading the contract data using signer "TypeError: checkProvider(...).call is not a function"

Tags: ethers.js, nodejs

I am creating an instance of singer by passing the pvkey and provider, but after creating the instance of the contract i am not able to interact with it.

```
const signer =  new ethers.Wallet(pvKey,apiKey);
const erc20_rw = new ethers.Contract(address, abi, signer);

// getting the name of contract
let name = await erc20_rw.name()

console.log("name of contract ", name);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `apiKey`? Based on the name, I'm guessing it's just a string of your api key for whatever node provider you have (e.g. an Infura or Alchemy key). However it *should* be an instance of Provider, which you can get by passing in a url and/or an api key to the function `ethers.getDefaultProvider`

Comment: thanks for help, i already solved it. as you said we have to pass provider instance in wallet instance